# How does parameter caching improve performance in ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, enterprise-library, data-access-layer

Looking to deepen my knowledge of ADO.NET - while reading through the Enterprise Library code I noticed they employ a technique called "parameter caching"

Can someone explain to me how this improves performance and what scenarios this helps?

Is the performance gain purely from the cost of construction of DbParameter objects or is there something else happening on the SQL Server side in terms of the query plan?

I would think that the first time you assemble the DbCommand object and wire-it-up with corresponding DbParameter objects, the SQL Server would at this point have cached an execution plan and subsequent calls to the same procedure with the same parameter templates would re-use the existing cached execution plan on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is purely to avoid database round trips incurred when calling [SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters.aspx):

> If the parameter information is known
>   in advance, it is more efficient to
>   populate the parameters collection by
>   setting the information explicitly.

Comment: Sorry to be daft, but when is DeriveParameters called?

Comment: The database family of classes have methods which allow you to 'DiscoverParameters' for stored procedures. This can be used to simply avoid having to type them in, or in a data access layer where you might do something like dynamically map the data members of a class onto the parameters of CRUD stored procs.

Comment: Does parameter caching add any benefit with day-to-day ADO.NET usage? eg setting a DbCommand.CommandType = StoredProcedure, specifying the stored proc name and then adding to it's Parameters collection? When would DiscoverParameters ever get called if you already knew the parameters for the stored proc in advance?

Comment: If you know the parameters at design time and explicitly set them, caching is not beneficial. Parameter caching is for situations where parameters are not known at design time - e.g. generalized library code that must function against any stored procedure.